# How to add an If statement in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script

I am trying to add an If Statement to my code.
The result I want to end up with is similar to this:

If C3:C = 'Y' then clear B3:B

The code below will clear B3:B, but I can't get an If statement to make this script run on the condition of another cell.

```
function clearData() {
  var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1zzPUsGTIyCBqi1J9HAoFafaxBSOntCit0lfucf8SL78").getSheetByName("Manual Requests");
  sheetActive.getRange('B3:B').clearContent();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function clearData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1zzPUsGTIyCBqi1J9HAoFafaxBSOntCit0lfucf8SL78");
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Manual Requests");
  var rgC=sh.getRange(3,3,sh.getLastRow()-2,1);
  var vC=rgC.getValues();
  var rgB=sh.getRange(3,2,sh.getLastRow()-2,1);
  var vB=rgB.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vC.length;i++) {
    if(vC[i][0]=='Y') {
      vB[i][0]='';
    }
  }
  rgB.setValues(vB);
}
```

Since Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript 1.6 then you can [refer here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6) to all questions of statement syntax.

Comment: Hi Cooper, thanks for your help! How do I add multiple ranges to clear in this script? I'm currently adding in a new line per column but I have 16 columns in total I'd like to clear based on the value of C